# using "Refine" option in Matlab's ode45

Tags: matlab, ode, numerical-integration

I am trying to use `ode45` in MAtlab and want to fix the number of points that MAtlab uses (number of time steps). Using the `'refine'` option in `ode45` seems not to help. For instance, if I set `'refine'` to be 10, Matlab returns an array of 101.
Changing `'RelTol'` and `'AbsTol'` also does not help either. I know that it is possible to write `tspan` as `[0,t1,t2,t3,...,tn]` and that solves this issue, but I'd like to fix number of points via the `'refine'` option.

Comment: Please provide the code showing how you're setting the options and calling `ode45`.

Comment: @horchler
code is

"options = odeset('RelTol',1e-3,'AbsTol',1e-3,'Refine',1);
[T,Y] = ode45(@prop,[0,delT/2,delT],present,options);"

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you misunderstand what the `'Refine'` option actually does. From the documentation for [`odeset`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/odeset.html#f92-1016858):

> Refine — If Refine is 1, the solver returns solutions only at the end of each time step. If Refine is n >1, the solver subdivides each time step into n smaller intervals and returns solutions at each time point. Refine does not apply when length(tspan)>2 or the ODE solver returns the solution as a structure.

In other words, setting `'Refine'` to 10 does not guarantee that you'll get 10 output points but rather that you'll get 10 output points *per integration time step*. In the case of an adaptive step size method like `ode45`, the solver chooses how big the steps are based on many criteria. If you want a given number of output points you must specify fixed time steps as you've already done via `tspan`. The [`linspace`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html) function might be helpful to you.

Another possibility is that you're not actually applying your options. Simply calling `odeset` is not sufficient. You must also remember to pass the output into `ode45`.

Comment: @AminR.: Did I answer your question? Is the use of `'Refine'` clear to you? If this answer was helpful to you please accept it. Thank you.